# When some editing in DataGridView without saving and click Exit button, Show WindowsForm do you want to save change in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, datagridview

As Microsoft Excel application, when some editing in cells without saving we click the close button, Show windows form do you want to save change?
As like this! i want to when some editing in DGV without saving click close button show winform do you want to save change? In winform have THREE buttons Save, Do not save and Cancel. And also DGV connected MS Access Database. Just i want to Controlling DGV...

Answer (score 1):

it will go some thing like this, but i think it will work only on databound datagridview

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentRowDirty)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("you have not saved the changes!\nDo you want to continue?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (result == DialogResult.No)
                e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is your datagirdview a databound datagridview if not then (dataGridView1.IsCurrentRowDirty) will not work you need to add some check to figur out that user has changed some thing and have not saved it

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [CellValueChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

and set to a bool value .

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, But i am not a programmer, Just create Fun! So, if you guide me step by step then i will be understand.  i am also using CellValueChange event but, appear Dialog MessageBox every cells when i insert data in DGV.